# How to optimize a hive query with multiple count(distinct...) on overlapping periods?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a huge paragraph hive query code like this below:

```
select 
count(distinct case when click_day between ${hiveconf:dt_180}  and ${hiveconf:dt_end} and recommend_flag=1  then productid else null end) as unique_hk_products_cnt_180d,
count(distinct case when click_day between ${hiveconf:dt_90}  and ${hiveconf:dt_end}  and recommend_flag=1 then productid else null end) as unique_hk_products_cnt_90d,
count(distinct case when click_day between ${hiveconf:dt_30}  and ${hiveconf:dt_end}  and recommend_flag=1 then productid else null end) as unique_hk_products_cnt_30d,
count(distinct case when click_day between ${hiveconf:dt_15}  and ${hiveconf:dt_end}  and recommend_flag=1 then productid else null end) as unique_hk_products_cnt_15d,
count(distinct case when click_day between ${hiveconf:dt_7}  and ${hiveconf:dt_end}  and recommend_flag=1 then productid else null end) as unique_hk_products_cnt_7d
from mytable ;
```

the only difference between these fields is the number of day, which represents the length of time window.
This make my query very large and it is difficult to make mistake.

dt_15 is just a string variable defined before:

```
set dt_15 = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(date_sub(current_date,15), 1, 4), SUBSTRING(date_sub(current_date,15), 6, 2), SUBSTRING(date_sub(current_date,15), 9, 2));
```

Any guys can help me reconstruct it more simple? like using loop to product fields in new table ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select  count (case when click_day between ${hiveconf:dt_180} and ${hiveconf:dt_end} then productid end) as unique_hk_products_cnt_180d
       ,count (case when click_day between ${hiveconf:dt_90}  and ${hiveconf:dt_end} then productid end) as unique_hk_products_cnt_90d
       ,count (case when click_day between ${hiveconf:dt_30}  and ${hiveconf:dt_end} then productid end) as unique_hk_products_cnt_30d
       ,count (case when click_day between ${hiveconf:dt_15}  and ${hiveconf:dt_end} then productid end) as unique_hk_products_cnt_15d
       ,count (case when click_day between ${hiveconf:dt_7}   and ${hiveconf:dt_end} then productid end) as unique_hk_products_cnt_7d

from   (select  click_day,recommend_flag,productid
               ,row_number() over 
                (
                    partition by    productid
                    order by        click_day desc    
                )   as rn

        from    mytable

        where   click_day between ${hiveconf:dt_180} and ${hiveconf:dt_end} 
            and recommend_flag=1
        ) t

where   rn = 1
```

P.s.
Any reason you are storing your dates in a non-standard form?

Comment: The output fields are must that can not be changed. that is to say, the result should be a horizontal table.

Comment: It is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
use build-in date function

```
set dt_15 = from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_sub(current_date,15),'yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyymmdd')
```

for setting value as this will remove concat and substring operation.

```
select 
count(case when click_day between ${hiveconf:dt_180}  and ${hiveconf:dt_end}   then productid else null end) as unique_hk_products_cnt_180d,
count(case when click_day between ${hiveconf:dt_90}  and ${hiveconf:dt_end}  then productid else null end) as unique_hk_products_cnt_90d,
count(case when click_day between ${hiveconf:dt_30}  and ${hiveconf:dt_end}  then productid else null end) as unique_hk_products_cnt_30d,
count(case when click_day between ${hiveconf:dt_15}  and ${hiveconf:dt_end}   then productid else null end) as unique_hk_products_cnt_15d,
count(case when click_day between ${hiveconf:dt_7}  and ${hiveconf:dt_end}   then productid else null end) as unique_hk_products_cnt_7d
from (select distinct click_day,productid where recommend_flag = 1 ) tmp ;
```

This will reduce the input volume. You can also put the `click_day < dt_end` if it is same for all the column and remove the between.

Comment: It does not have the same logic as the original post. Removing duplicates of productid  per click_day (if there are any) does not prevent from counting duplicate productid for a range of dates.